# SQL statement for average in specific row values group columns

Tags: sql

I've my table like the format below, I want to write sql statement for display column average for test1 and test2, column for main and column for position.[image]

I've tried this sql:

```
select name, average as final,AVG(case when exam in('test1','test2') ) as testa 
from table 
where exam='main' 
order by main final 
group by name;
```

But It Does not working....help please
I want results to appear like this:
[image]

Comment: what is position here?

Comment: I think `AVG(case when exam in('test1','test2') )` is case sensitive

Comment: Please fill in your desired results.  It is not obvious what these mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following.

```
Select t1.name, average12, main, rownum from (
    select t1.name as name, t1.avg(average) as average12, t2.mainexam as main 
    from <table> t1 left join <table> t2 
    on t1.id = t2.id 
    where t2.exam = 'Main' 
    group by t1.name, t2.mainexam
) order by main desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query for SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
      e.name AS 'Student Name'
    , CAST( AVG( CASE WHEN e.Exam IN ( 'Test1', 'Test2' ) THEN e.average END ) AS FLOAT ) AS 'Test Average'
    , e2.average AS 'Main Exam'
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY e2.average DESC ) AS 'Position'

FROM 
    exams AS e

    INNER JOIN exams AS e2
        ON e2.name = e.name
        AND e2.exam = 'Main'

GROUP BY 
      e.name
    , e2.average

ORDER BY 
    e2.average DESC
```

Output is:

```
+--------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| Student Name | Test Average | Main Exam | Position |
+--------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| Name1        |         60.5 |        89 |        1 |
| Name2        |         49.5 |        63 |        2 |
| Name3        |           73 |        38 |        3 |
+--------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer if you feel it has resolve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This simple query averages Test1 and Test2. Depending on your dbms, you might have trouble with reserved words like *name*.

```
select name, cast(avg(average) as integer)
from test
where exam = 'Test1'
   or exam = 'Test2'
group by name;
```

This simple query gives you the values for "main".

```
select name, average as main
from test
where exam = 'Main'
```

Put them together in a common table expression, and join on "name".

```
with test_avg as (
  select name, cast(avg(average) as integer)
  from test
  where exam = 'Test1'
     or exam = 'Test2'
group by name
), main_avg as (
  select name, average as main
  from test
  where exam = 'Main'
)
select t1.name, t1.avg, t2.main
from test_avg t1
inner join main_avg t2
on t1.name = t2.name;
```

```
name      avg  main
--
Name1     61   89
Name2     50   63
Name3     73   38
```

I don't know what you mean by *position*. If you're trying to rank the rows from highest average to lowest average, you might do it like this.

```
with test_avg as (
  select name, cast(avg(average) as integer)
  from test
  where exam = 'Test1'
     or exam = 'Test2'
group by name
), main_avg as (
  select name, average as main
  from test
  where exam = 'Main'
)
select t1.name, t1.avg, t2.main, row_number() over (order by avg desc) as position
from test_avg t1
inner join main_avg t2
on t1.name = t2.name
order by position;
```

```
name      avg  main  position
--
Name3     73   38    1
Name1     61   89    2
Name2     50   63    3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the max here.... Its very simple

```
select a.*,row_number() over (order by main desc) as position from
 (
    select name,
    AVG(case when exam in ('Test1','Test2') then Average else null end ) as testa,
    max(case when exam in ('Main') then Average else null end) as main
    from abc 
    group by name
) a
    order by name;
```

Output :

```
name    testa   main    position1
Name1   60.50   89        1
Name2   49.50   63        2
Name3   73.00   38        3
```